# https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0 content extraction issue

Tags: java, itext

I am using  <s>iText-4.2.0</s> https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0 project for pdf page content extraction. For some pdf files, it works properly. But for some files it's **just return page no as content**. 
Any help on this?

code:

```
//in constructor
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
reader = new PdfReader(fis);
pdfTextExtractor = new PdfTextExtractor(reader);

//in extractContent method
return pdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pageNo);
```

Comment: (1.) There is no such thing as iText 4.2. If you have such a version, the use of the name iText is misleading, because there has never been an official release with that version number. (2.) The most recent, **official** version of iText has improved content extraction. I'm going to vote to close this question as it is about a problem that can be solved by upgrading.

Comment: Hello Buno, https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0 is the repo i am using. Its the final free version according to the readme.

Comment: The problem cannot be solved by upgrading if the user's project is incompatible with the AGPL.

Comment: Yes Kevin, my project cannot go with AGPL.

Comment: ymasory is unknown to iText Group NV. That project is **not an official version.** Contact ymasory and you'll discover that you won't get any decent support. If your project cannot go with AGPL, there is always the option to get a commercial license that is compatible with your project.

Comment: First of all, without the PDFs in question, we can only guess. A good guess has to do with Bruno's item (2), though. The text extraction capabilities of those old iText versions were more a proof of concept, less something for use in production. E.g. those versions ignored text in form xobjects completely. My guess would be that that is your problem. And the solution is either updating or spending very much work in improving that version.